# I need to install i tar.gz file, but nothing on here helped

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

Look. I have looked everywhere for the answer but I cant find it, so here goes. i need to install a tar.gz file. Ok, ok, yes I am a beginner , but I really need help. I want to install prisonarchitect-alpha26b-linux.tar.gz. the file directory is /home/rhys/Downloads/prisonarchitect-alpha26b-linux.tar.gz. and I am running ubuntu version 14.04 32bit. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: what did you do to install it ? did you read the README or instauctions fro prisonarchitect ? Hard to know from what little you posted.

Comment: also, running third party alpha (development) releases are not well supported here. you may have better luck contacting prisonarchitect directly.

Comment: I remember this bit of learner frustration! PITA until you get it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you need to install it? Try just extracting the file and look for executables (things that you can run).

Comment: you are a lifesaver! i got so frustrated!!! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Installing tar archives;**

Step 1, unpack it - generally best to make a new directory, cd to it, then do this as SOME .tar.gz files will unpack all over the current directory - most won't. The command looks like this:

`tar -xvhz </home/rhys/Downloads/prisonarchitect-alpha26b-linux.tar.gz` (or you can use an f in the options, ie -xvhzf instead of the <).

Step 2, have a look at the files. Most of the time there will be a file called 'configure'.

`./configure` mostly works - you may find you have to install other stuff, there's usually no guidance re which other stuff.... the error messages are the clues.

Once you have persuaded configure to work without errors, `make` should compile it, and `sudo make install` should install it - Your Mileage May Vary! Some folk use other systems. There's usually a readme or an install file, so named.

Comment: There is no way to know what is in an archive. tar.gz != source code . Some tar.gz contain pre-compiled binaries. Also ./configure (compiling source code) is not going to work unless you install build-essential (well at least make and gcc) + all the necessary dependencies.

Comment: Indeed; however the majority will respond to this treatment, if it's an "installation" - a lot of stuff does come in this form and, as a beginner, I sweated blood over this one many years ago - and it's a bit.. impenetrable... if you overcomplicate it.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok. i understand now! Sorta... Thanks a bunch!